# SQL: Select latest balance per unique users in a table transactional log

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, uniqueidentifier

I have a TABLE of logs of transnational balances of the following form

```
TIMESTAMP         |   Name  |   BALANCE
------------------+---------+-----------
1/6/2022 17:57:51 | User_1  |     45
1/6/2022 15:57:27 | User_2  |     15
1/6/2022 12:27:27 | User_1  |    251    
1/6/2022 11:17:22 | User_3  |   1500    
1/6/2022 10:11:22 | User_2  |   5301
1/6/2022 10:57:18 | User_3  |   2351
1/6/2022 10:23:14 | User_4  |   1542
1/6/2022 10:17:09 | User_4  |    424
```

I looking to pull a table of the following form

```
TIMESTAMP         |   Name  |   BALANCE
------------------+---------+-----------
1/6/2022 17:57:51 | User_1  |     45
1/6/2022 15:57:27 | User_2  |     15
1/6/2022 11:17:22 | User_3  |   1500    
1/6/2022 10:23:14 | User_4  |   1542
```

I want to take out a table with the latest time and the last balance. I tried

```
select 
    s1.Name, s1.Balance, s1.timestamp, s2.Email_s2
from 
    TABLE s1
right join 
    (select 
         Name, max(timestamp) as timestamp
     from TABLE
     group by Name
     order by date desc) s2 on s1.Email = s2.Email_s2
where 
    s1.Balance is not null
order by 
    Timestamp desc
```

But the output still shows duplicated values. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For the top there doesn't exist any bigger.

```
select Timestamp, Name, Balance
from TABLE t
where Balance is not null
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from TABLE t2
    where t2.Name = t.Name
      and t2.Timestamp > t.Timestamp
      and t2.Balance is not null
) 
order by Timestamp desc;
```

For they are number 1.

```
select Timestamp, Name, Balance
from (
    select t.*
    , row_number() over (partition by Name order by Timestamp desc) as rownum
    from TABLE t
    where Balance is not null
) q
where rownum = 1
order by Timestamp desc;
```

Surely, they are the MAX.

```
select t.Timestamp, t.Name, t.Balance
from TABLE t
inner join 
(
    select Name, MAX(Timestamp) AS MaxTimestamp
    from TABLE
    where Balance is not null
    group by Name
) q on q.Name = t.Name
   AND q.MaxTimestamp = t.Timestamp  -- we want only the max
order by t.Timestamp desc;
```